"arbitrarily close" and "sufficiently close" confusion in a limit definition
After $2$ minutes $22$ seconds on this video, Dr. Linda Green said on an informal definition of the limit of a function that

For any function $f(x)$ and for real numbers $a$ and $L$, $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$ means that $f(x)$ gets arbitrarily close to $L$ as $x$
gets arbitrarily close to $a$. In other words, as $x$ heads towards
$a$, $f(x)$ heads towards $L$.

But are the statement "$f(x)$ gets arbitrarily close to $L$ as $x$ gets arbitrarily close to $a$" and the statement "as $x$ heads towards $a$, $f(x)$ heads towards $L$" really the same? Didn't she mean "as close as we want to" there by the phrase "arbitrarily close"? Or she meant "closer and closer" by the phrase "arbitrarily close"?
When we talk about the definition of the limit of a function more informally, we can say the statement that "as $x$ heads towards $a$, $f(x)$ heads towards $L$" (which is similar to "as $x$ gets closer and closer to $a$, $f(x)$ gets closer and closer to $L$"). But when we talk about the definition of the limit of a function less informally, shouldn't we say that "$f(x)$ gets arbitrarily close to $L$ as $x$ gets sufficiently close to $a$" (though she did say it after a few seconds)? Are the statements "$f(x)$ gets arbitrarily close to $L$ as $x$ gets arbitrarily close to $a$" and "$f(x)$ gets arbitrarily close to $L$ as $x$ gets sufficiently close to $a$" same? Or "$f(x)$ gets arbitrarily close to $L$ as $x$ gets sufficiently close to $a$" is just a better way of saying the definition of the limit of a function than "$f(x)$ gets arbitrarily close to $L$ as $x$ gets arbitrarily close to $a$"?
Is the statement "$f(x)$ gets arbitrarily close to $L$ as $x$ gets arbitrarily close to $a$" appropriate for an informal definition of the limit of a function?
Edit: After asking it there, I asked it on mathoverflow. But my question on mathoverflow was migrated to Mathematics Stack Exchange here and got answers too. I also asked it on the comment box of the video, and Dr. Linda replied that

As you probably know, the precise definition of $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$
is that for any (small) number  $\epsilon > 0$, there is a (small) number
$\delta > 0$ so that whenever $x$ is within $\delta$ units of $a$, $f(x)$ will be
within $\epsilon$ units of $L$. I use imprecise language in this intro
video to get the idea of a limit across, without overwhelming my
students with the more precise notation. The informal language is good
enough for many straightforward limit situations, but not good enough
for more complicated situations. Maybe a slightly more precise but
still informal definition might be that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$ if $f(x)$
gets and stays arbitrarily close to $L$ when $x$ is sufficiently close to
$a$.


Not sure what the question is.  Vague English phrases are vague.  That's why mathematicians introduce precise definitions for the things they discuss.   We don't know what "she" meant.  But it shouldn't matter.   Don't worry about vague phrases, focus on definitions.

""f(x) gets arbitrarily close to L as x gets arbitrarily close to a" and the statement "as x heads towards a, f(x) heads towards L" really the same?"  I don't think so.  We can "head toward" something without ever getting within a hundred miles.  If we consider $x$ going from $0$ and "heading toward" $7$ and compare it to $x^2 + 3$ "heading" toward $61846$ we see that as $x$ gets closer to $7$ $x^2+3$ does get closer to $61846$... After all $6^2 + 3 = 29$ is closer to $61846$ then $0^2 + 3=3$ is.

I think the best intuitive way to think of it is this:  If we wish to get $f(x)$ as close to $L$ as we like by taking $x$ close to $a$ we can do so, because for any teeny distance $\epsilon > 0$ there is a coresponding smallish distance $\delta$ where by taking an $x$ that is within a distance of $\delta$ from $a$ , that will guarantee that $f(x)$ will be within $\epsilon$ of $L$.

Please do not make two identical posts.

Dear @fleablood, could you please submit your comments on the post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4914544/arbitrarily-close-and-sufficiently-close-confusion-in-a-limit-definition? Actually after asking there, I asked this question on MathOverflow and it got migrated to Math Stack Exchange. Since having duplicate questions floating around is problematic, one of the two posts need to be deleted. As the other post is more "active", I'm requesting you to post your comments (which you think benefit) there too.

Dear @lulu, could you please submit your comments on the post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4914544/arbitrarily-close-and-sufficiently-close-confusion-in-a-limit-definition? Actually after asking there, I asked this question on MathOverflow and it got migrated to Math Stack Exchange. Since having duplicate questions floating around is problematic, one of the two posts need to be deleted. As the other post is more "active", I'm requesting you to post your comments (which you think benefit) there too.

The video looks like to be from a first calculus course. We typically don't introduce the formal definition of limit, but here it is: for each $\epsilon > 0,$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x - y| < \delta.$ What that means - when $x$ and $y$ are near enough, $f(x)$ and $L$ are near enough.
Because this definition can overwhelm first-year students, we use the informal language previously mentioned. This is good enough for now - math minors and majors will tune this up when they take a first analysis course.

It occurs to me that it might be useful, in a first course in calculus, for them to show examples where the hypothesized value is not the limit.  Then show what contradiction happens when you try apply the $\delta - \epsilon$ definition, or do something that is "informal."  Usually, all the examples are showing that "L" is the limit as opposed to "L" not being the limit.

I dunno... when, rarely, I teach these things in ordinary calc classes, it's usually more than enough to just get them to do one or two kinds of very simple examples.

Dear @Sean Roberson, could you please submit your answer on the post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4914544/arbitrarily-close-and-sufficiently-close-confusion-in-a-limit-definition? Actually after asking there, I asked this question on MathOverflow and it got migrated to Math Stack Exchange. Since having duplicate questions floating around is problematic, one of the two posts need to be deleted. It seems that other post is more "active" and hence I'm requesting you to post your answer there too.
